# What's the best way to update a document in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having difficulty understanding what's the better way to update a document in Mongoose with Node.js. If you set the properties of a document like so:

```js
const oldUser = UserModel.findOne({ name: user.userid });
oldUser.firstName = user.firstName || oldUser.firstName;
oldUser.lastName = user.lastName || oldUser.lastName;
```

then when you reach the document.save() method inside a pre-save hook your document is not set as modified. The isModified() is always false. However, when you use `set()` you do get the document set to true for `isModified()` for example:

```js
const oldUser = await UserModel.findOne({ name: user.name });
oldUser.set('firstName', user.firstName || oldUser.firstName);
oldUser.set('lastName', user.lastName || oldUser.lastName);
```

Which is a better way to update a document and check for if it really was modified or not, and is there a better approach that's different than these two? Any tips, advice, or suggestions appreciated!

Comment: What is the use case? I believe `save()` won't mark it as modified since it will just overwrite the whole document, but `set()` modifies one part of an existing document, thus it will mark it as updated. I think if you want to check the modified status, using `set()` is the right method.